# What is the meaning of "N" in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

The meaning of "jackrabbit" in Oxford dictionary is:

a large N American hare(=an animal like a large rabbit) with very long ears.

My question is what is the meaning of "N" in this sentence?

Comment: It stands for *North*.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: The four [cardinal directions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction) (North, South, East and West) are often abbreviated to their initial letters (N, S, E and W).  So you often see N America, S America, E Timor, and W Viginia). Sometimes the other points get abbreviated to two or three letters as well so you get things like "NE England" and "a SSW" wind.j